# Create cache for user profile image

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to android. I've created an app that user can upload their profiles and those profile images will be stored in firebases storage. When they will login again those images will be retrieved from firebases to display in their profiles. But the matter is it takes a few minutes for image to display after user login. I think creating a cache may solve this problem or is there any better methods ?? You may recommend me otherwise tell me how to create cache. Thank !

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to cache your image on the device side.

1. Download image manually, save to local. Then next time opening up, load the image from local first. After that, download Firebase Storage Image. After downloaded, replace that newer image with that ImageView.

This can help you show your image sooner, but not save bandwidth usage. You can try option 2, which will automatically help you.

2. Using a 3rd-party library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso). I prefer Glide, that caching info will be here, you should check directly from owner site. https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html